# WSOD after chaning subtheme templates

Tags: 7, theming, wsod

I've added the `page.tpl.php` and the `theme.api.php` file to my bootstrap subtheme's template folder, refeshed and everything was fine.

I added `<h1>TEST</h1>` to the `page.tpl.php` to check where it would show up. Moved it a bit until I was satisfied where it was.

However I changed my mind and deleted the files in the template folder and got the WSOD...

The two files are still in the original folder and adding them back to the templates folder does nothing.

Is there a way to fix this? Right now the whole site is blank and no errors show up.

Checking the watchdog table leads me to this function:

```
// Use a default value if $message is not set.
  if (empty($message)) {
    // The exception message is run through check_plain() by _drupal_decode_exception().
    $message = '%type: !message in %function (line %line of %file).';
  }
```

Comment: I do not know the exact answer, but put those files at the place where it was like previous setting. Then using Drush clear cache.

Comment: I am unable to because the site running an a shared hosting server (to avoid migrating the site) and I do not have the rights to do so...

Comment: You need to either look in your php logs or look at the variables inside the watchdog table to see the actual error, without it nobody can really help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing the caching tables did the trick! Thanks CodeNext!

However I could not use Drush, so I cleared them manually in PHPmyAdmin using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271951/delete-all-records-in-a-table-of-mysql-in-phpmyadmin)